# How to Export Very Large Clob in PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to Export a very large amount of data as XML using plsql (around 80000000 characters). Unfortunately I'm currently unable to use FILE_UTL due to system privileges, and have been suggested to store it in a local table. Annoyingly, this table is cutting off the data at around 800 characters. While I'm aware plsql has a limit of 4000 characters, I'm still unsure how to proceed, and to keep my data stored so I can manually export it, or automatically do so.
TIA

Comment: Update: I've managed to get the CLOB to save into the table, but it seems to be only there so long as I never confirm it is there, except to check the size. as soon as I bring it up in sql developer to view, or perform a select on it, the clob is truncated to around 100 characters.

Comment: PL/SQL does not have a limit of 4000 characters.

Comment: What kind of privilege issues are preventing you from using UTL_FILE?  Do you not have access to the package, to a specific file, or to any directories on the server?

Comment: I don't have the ability to create a directory, nor be able to see any that do exist on the server